# How to get an Alertdialog with the background out of focus (fuzzy)

Tags: android, list, background, focus, android-alertdialog

I know how to make `AlertDialog`'s of various types. But, how can I make an `AlertDialog` with the background *fuzzy* as if it is out of focus (i.e. like using a telephoto lens)?

Whenever I search for 'focus' the result relaits to something like the `onFocus` commands, etc. which isn't what I mean.

An example would be if you press the power button on your phone, a list pops up and the background goes *fuzzy*.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an AlertDialog itself, it's a plain Activity themed as Dialog.

You need a simple Activity and in manifest file just add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

```
<activity android:name=".utils.TextEntryActivity"
            android:label="Type in the value" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```